# Deezer website mp3 player implementation

Tags: javascript, layout, mp3

I just had a quick question about the mp3 player on [deezer.com](http://www.deezer.com/en/) 
I want to implement something similar on a website I'm trying to make and wanted to know how I would go about doing so. 
More specifically how to make it have a floating part which become slightly smaller on the top of all pages of the website.

At the moment I know HTML/CSS but it looks like the mp3 player is using some sort of script.

Any help would be much appreciated!

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

It's using Flash as its MP3 streamer and player, just right click the icons and you'll see. It dynamically loads and streams MP3s from the server. Flashkit has a collection of pre-made movies you may be able to utilize in building your own. [FlashKit Search: MP3 XML](http://www.flashkit.com/search.php?term=mp3+xml&cat=movies&per=10&field=Description&andor=and&page=1&submit=Submit)

I've coded an MP3 streamer in the past, fairly straightforward to do, using XML as its data source: [Real Estate Showcase Project](http://www.louierd.com/website_design_showcase.htm)